# Show that there are infinitely many pairs of integers $x$ and $y$ satisfying $x+y=100$ and $\gcd(x,y)=5$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I know this question has an answer but I want to check if my proof is correct.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ Let $x$ and $y$ be two integers satisfying the above conditions. Then as $\gcd(x,y)=5$ then $x$ and $y$ are multiples of 5. Now we notice that each multiple of 5 is either even hence divisible by 2 or odd, and that $x$ and $y$ can't both be even because then the $\gcd(x,y)$ $\geq$10.
If one of $x$ and $y$ were odd then the sum $x+y$ is odd which is impossible as 100 is even. What remains is that both $x$ and $y$ are odd.
Finally, we know that $x+y=100$ then if we let $y=2k+1=5m$ where $k$ and $m$ are integers then $x=100-2k-1=2(50-k)-1$ which is odd, and $x=100-5m=5(20-m)$ which is divisible by 5.

Comment: What happens when $m=5$?

Comment: Your proof looks correct, but a few small things. 1) you don't need to introduce $x$ and $y$, as they are simply $a$ and $b$ respectively in the problem. 2) You have to show that there are infinitely many integers $k$ that satisfy $2k+1=5m$. In this case, $m=2j+1$ and $k=5j+2$ for any integer $j$. Showing the infinity of this over the set of integers would imply the infinity of the integer pairs $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @MrPie I see thanks! Just one more question do I edit my proof or is that against MSE rules?

Comment: @player3236 $m=5$ means that $y=25$ and $x=75$ hence the $gcd(x,y)=25$ which contradicts the condition $gcd(x,y)=5$. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You can edit your proof! You can also write it below as an answer.

Comment: It might be easier to note that If $x = 5k$ and $y=100-5k$ then $x+y =100$ and $\gcd(x,y) = \gcd(5k,100-5k)=\gcd(5k,100) = 5\cdot \gcd(k,20)$.  You will have a solution for every integer that is relatively prime to $20=2^2*5$. And there are infinitely many such integers. (Every integer that is neither divisible by $2$ or by $5$ will do.)

Comment: Hint: $\ 5 = (x,100-x) = (x,100) \iff 1 = (x/5,20).\ $ So it is equivalent to show that there are infinitely many integers coprime to $20.\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not prove the statement. The task is to prove that there are *infinitely* many pair $(x,y)$ that meet the conditions. Instead, you establish that *if* there is one pair $(x,y)$ that meets the conditions, both $x$ and $y$ must be odd.

Maybe you are thinking that if both $x$ and $y$ are odd (along with being multiples of $5$ and summing to $100$) then the conditions will be met, and that provides infinitely many solutions since there are infinitely many such pairs. But as a commenter points out, at least some of those pairs like $(25,75)$ do not meet the gcd condition.

The question asks if your proof is correct, and doesn't ask for a correct proof in the case that it is not. So I will withhold offering a correct proof. But a hint is to just let the pair be $(x,100-x)$ to eliminate $y$. And then think about how you could design $x$ in *infinitely* many ways to meet *both* of the conditions.